# jquery how to find element searching against attribute name

Tags: jquery, attributes, css-selectors

I have a quite specific query, how can I find all elements with a certain attribute.

My elements have attributes which follow a specific pattern, here are some examples:

```
 <div data-jtemplate-href="x"></div>
 <span data-jtemplate-text="x"></span>
 <input data-jtemplate-something="x"/>
 <table data-jtemplate-else="x"></table>
```

as you can see, all my elements have attributes where the name has the prefix 'data-jtemplate', how can I find all elements with the attribute prefix data-jtemplate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own expression, see http://jsfiddle.net/6pCh4/

```
$.expr[":"].dataAttrStartingWith = function(el, i, m) {
  for (var p in $(el).data()) {
     if (p.substring(0, m[3].length) === m[3]) return true;    
  }
  return false;
};  


console.log($('body *:dataAttrStartingWith(jtemplate)'))
```

this expression will filter all elements with a `data-jtemplate-*` attribute (As you can see in the fiddle I've added another element that was correctly discarded by this filter)

Of course this is customizable with other `data-*` attribute (just change `jtemplate` in the selector)

Comment: did not know you could add your own expression. Now I do :) cheers

Comment: Mind you, if you're doing this repeatedly, I suspect that finding a class will be more efficient for the browser to execute.

Answer (score 3):

Just add another attribute (data- or otherwise) that you *can* search on:

```
 <div class="jtemplate" data-jtemplate-href="x"></div>
 <span class="jtemplate" data-jtemplate-text="x"></span>
 <input class="jtemplate" data-jtemplate-something="x"/>
 <table class="jtemplate" data-jtemplate-else="x"></table>
```

No need to define it as a CSS style. Now all you need is the selector `$('.jtemplate')` to get all those elements.

Comment: what if these elements have their own class that is not same for all?

Comment: You can add multiple classes to any DOM element, separated by spaces, and they will all be applied to that element: `<p class="jtemplate big medium small">...</p>`

Comment: no need to add other classes, just create a custom expression

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you convert your mark up according to this:

```
<div "data-jtemplate"="href-x"></div>
<span "data-jtemplate"="text-y"></span>
<input "data-jtemplate"="something-z" />
<table "data-jtemplate"="else-v"></table>
```

now you can do a pretty simple search:

```
var jTemplate = $("*[data-jtemplate]") // selects all elements with that prefix
$("*[data-jtemplate^='href-']", jTemplate) // select all elements with href in jTemplate scope
$("*[data-jtemplate^='text-']").each( function(i, ele)
{
   var attr = $(this).attr("data-jtemplate").replace("text-",""); // gives you actual value of the attribute
});
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<div 'data-jtemplate'='{href:"http://example.com",text:"example",attr:10,private:false}'></div> 
// {href:"http://example.com",text:"example",attr:10,private:false} -> easy to create on the server

var json = $("[data-jtemplate]").eq(0).attr("data-jtemplate");
var parsedData = $.parseJSON(json);
var href = parsedData.href; // etc -- easy to access
```

Comment: But what if he wants more than one `data-jtemplate` value per DOM element? i.e. `<div data-jtemplate-href="x" data-jtemplate-text="y"></div>`

Comment: then class, idd, you can use special class, or you can add logic like that: data-jtemplate='{text:"val",href:"http://qq.com",else:"nom-nom"}' - then you can simply parse it as JSON and you can eliminate all the need for writing parsing expressions;